# How to control sharing accounts from one user to another?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an app that has in-app purchases where users can purchase set of videos and there are ten of these sets. Now, before they do this they have to sign up for this app using their personal e-mail (not necessarily their phone's primary e-mail).
Since they have to log in this app, I was planning that they get the right to open the app and the set of videos they purchased from whatever device they use.

**Problem:**

After thinking about this and since this app is only directed towards local audience, I am afraid that users will pass their accounts to each other and my customer number will decrease.

**Solution I thought about:**

I will put a message when the users buy the set of videos that says: "These videos will only be viewed from the device you download it on". Which means I will use certain flags to ensure that an account will download them once. So that if someone is to share an account s/he won't be able to download because they where already downloaded.

**Question:**

If I do like this then if the user uninstalls this app, s/he will lose all the videos they purchased. Thus, if they install it again, they will have to buy the set of videos again. I am not sure if professional apps let the users have what they purchased back if they reinstalled the app or not.

So, is there a way that I can still use the solution that I thought about and still have my users regain what they bought before they uninstalled the app? Or do you have a completely different suggestion that can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Account sharing is a big topic. Daily business for Netflix and Amazon.

I'm not a big fan of your solution because of all the restrictions. I would suggest following approach:

- User signs up in your App
- You create a unique ID on the device (GUID - https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids)
- You store this data on the database plus the `GUID` on the device

You can now verify that the user has valid access.

I would suggest adding another field like `max_guids=2`. So that if the user looses the device he can still access his data (yes, this also means 1 single device sharing is possible, therefore you can detect irregularity with login sessions and ban the user).

Sounds better?

Comment: From what I understand GUID is a unique generated string, now when I save this GUID in the database and locally (maybe you mean shared prefrences), then when user uninstalls the app the local data is deleted right? How would this solve it then?

Comment: Absolutely correct. That's why I suggested to allow more than 1 `GUID` per user. If the user uses a new GUID, block the old one(s).

Comment: But this means that when a user on the same device uninstalls an app on the device, then when s/he reinstalls the app they are blocked because they generated new GUID right? If this is the case then this is not efficient don't you think? Or maybe I misunderstood what you mean?

Comment: If the user decides to reinstall it or install it on another device or hand his account over to a friend it would all be the same case...a new `GUID` will be created for his account if he is allowed to (`max_guids=x`). From this time he can only use his account on the new phone with the new `GUID`, because the old ones are blocked -> no sharing possible.

Comment: Is this the same thing as getting the device id and storing it in the database and allowing access if the current device id matches?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no reliable of getting a device id. Plus I guess you want the user to allow to change device or reinstall at least once. This is just a very quick solution. You can also restrict it further by location or creating a hash of device specific properties.

Comment: If getting the device id was straight forward, I could have allowed atleast 2 devices to log in from same account. I don't know why android and ios doesn't allow a clear way to get device ID.

Comment: it's up to the manufacturer and can be modified on rooted devices.